# Server freeze on flushing ipfw

Tags: freebsd, ipfw

I got strange problem with `ipfw` on FreeBSD 8.2, the problem is when I'm trying to flush the `ipfw` , by the following command:

`/sbin/ipfw -q -f flush`

or

`/sbin/ipfw flush` and then `y`

My dedicated server freezes, and ISP need to hard reboot it.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your server most likely did not freeze, it was unreachable. The default rule for ipfw is to deny everything. You can recompile the kernel with " options IPFIREWALL_DEFAULT_TO_ACCEPT" set, or add ";ipfw add allow all " to your command (or build a script that flushes and adds your rules at once).

Comment: Thats what ISP administrator did told me. I'm now in the rescue mode , and while entering the commands from the question I got the following notice: `ipfw: setsockopt(IP_FW_FLUSH): Protocol not available`.

Comment: I throwed my computer thru the window. That solved the problem, thank you.

Comment: Next time try to use /usr/share/examples/ipfw/change_rules.sh That script change rules as desired and wait for confirmation. If no confirmation occured, script treat that as lockup and rollback previous working config to unlock firewall.